# Can I run an integrated nomad/consul cluster with windows servers and linux clients?

Tags: consul, nomad

I am migrating a standard all-linux nomad/consul cluster where the nomad/consul servers use almost no resources with our workloads, and spinning up dedicated linux VMs just for them in our new environment seems a bit wasteful, when the environment I am moving to has multiple windows VMs with spare capacity which I could use for the nomad server and consul server processes to give me the necessary redundancy.

So my question boils down to: If I have the consul server and nomad server processes exclusively on windows and the nomad agent and consul agent processes exclusively on linux-- will they all just get along?  The nomad jobs are all dockerized except for a native system prometheus exporter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Consul and Nomad are operating system agnostic. You can use a mix of OS's within your cluster without issue. The main requirement is that you have direct IP connectivity between the agents (i.e., no NAT), low latency (sub 10ms), and the required ports opened for Consul and/or Nomad agent communication.

See https://www.consul.io/docs/install/ports and https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/install/production/requirements#ports-used for more detail.